# Fedora 14 default kernel config

Tags: android, x86, kernel, config, fedora

I am looking for the default kernel config file(s) of a current install of Fedora 14.
I'm trying to build Android-X86 for my Motion M1400, but can not find a proper .config for the kernel (and setting everything by hand is a pita).

The Fedora Core 4's instructions' /usr/src/linux folder does not exist, so I can't do a make oldconfig there sadly.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every kernel rpm.

/boot/config-`uname -r`

Answer (score 0):

Check out /proc/config.gz. If enabled in kernel (should be) gives the current kernel's gzipped config.

Comment: That was my first try, there's no config.gz :S

Comment: http://kernel-seeds.org/ is supposed to have preconfigured configs, no sure about Android. I am usually quite anal about kernel config so I do it myself.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that too, that's why I wanted a preconfigured config directly from my device (through installation it should make one, directly for this hw).