# Where I can find ubuntu 12.04 kernel .config file?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-12.04, config

I was playing around with rt kernel and I made changes in my on machine config file but forgot to keep the backup. From where I can download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS .config file?
Thanks

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28047/where-can-i-get-the-11-04-kernel-config-file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is very similar to [Fedora 14 default kernel config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611897/fedora-14-default-kernel-config)

The answer is:

```
/boot/config-`uname -r`
```